# Facebook Fan Gate

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm building a php page, which will have different urls like:

http://example.com/fb.php?id=1

and so on..

I made facebook fan gate and it actually works with static pages:
But with variables it doesn't work and I have no idea why.
I need to get permissions here:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'canvas' => 1,
    'fbconnect' => 1,
    'display' => 'page',
    'req_perms' => 'user_likes',
    'next' => 'http://example.com/fb.php',
    'cancel_url'=> 'http://example.com/fb.php'
));
```

I need to put here the variable, in next url and cancel_url 
Like http://example.com/fb.php?id=1
but it doesn't work

Comment: I need something like:                             http://site.com/fb.php?id=$id

Comment: What do yo mean by "it does not work"? Also, you don't need more than one "cancel_url" it should have only one url.

Comment: I mean, after getting permissions, I get url http://site.com/fb.php?id=$id not http://site.com/fb.php?id=1 or id=2

Comment: I need something like that: $id=$_GET['id'];                                                and url http://site.com/fb.php?id=$id

Comment: In the "next" parameter just put *'http://site.com/fb.php?id=' . $PAGE_NUM* or something like that

Comment: may be you should check the difference between single quotes and double quotes in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the desired argument to URL passed as `next` or `cancel_url`. If you want to

Also note that `req_perms` is called `scope` (for a long time) and until you change that no permissions will be granted to your app (aside basic, which not really a permission).

Next code supposed to do what you want (I've omitted deprecated/removed parameters and `display` which is by default equal to `page`):

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'user_likes',
  'next' => 'http://site.com/fb.php?id=1',
  'cancel_url'=> 'http://site.com/fb.php?id=1'
));
```

`getLoginUrl` will use current URL for `next` and `cancel_url` by default, so if you need to visit current page after the user authorize or cancels your authorization step this can be simply:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'user_likes'
));
```

Please read [documentation on `Facebook::getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) for more details